# How to run my time sensitive file delete script constantly on my web server

Tags: php, html, server, xampp, image-uploading

I have an image uploading website, and I'd like to allow for users to select how long they wish the file to be uploaded for, using:

```html
<select>
   <option>1 Hour</option>
   <option>12 Hours</option>
   <option>24 Hours</option>
</select>

<?php
   $live_for_seconds = X
?>

//Where X is the <select> option above.
```

Then, the server will allow the file to stay uploaded for the selected time duration before deleting itself.

Currently, the upload.php will look through each file in the upload directory and see if it's been stored for 24 hours, then delete it. This check happens every time BEFORE someone triggers an upload.

1. How can I have this check constantly running on my xampp server, without needing it to be triggered by a file upload to save on performance?
2. How can I ensure each file remembers how long it's meant to be uploaded for based on what option the user picks as shown above? So, this check can automatically delete files which have overstayed their welcome.

```php
//Check for files stored for longer than 24 hours

foreach (glob($target_dir."*") as $file) {

   if(time() - filectime($file) > 86400) {
      unlink($file);
   }

}

//Proceed to upload file~
```

86400 seconds, being 24 hours would be the $live_for_seconds decided in the   above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRON on your server to run a php file to check if time to delete has occurred. For instance you can run php file for every 1 hour to check if a file need to be deleted based on your time in seconds. 
CRON

```
 0 */2 * * *  /LOCATION_TO_YOUR_PHP_FILE
```

In your PHP code you can check if the time to delete an image has reached.